# Validate login form with JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication

I want to be able to either send a user to a restricted area or return some text that says `Email and or password do not exist` or something similar. I'm having trouble getting this to work as whether or not the `email` and `password` are correct **NOTHING** happens. I'm sending the form to the `index` page where the script to run this sits. Not sure why I'm not redirecting or getting any kind of errors.

The restricted page checks if a `$_SESSION` variable `isset()`, if not then send them back home.

### JS

```
loginBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  ajaxRequests.login(`login_email=${ loginEmail.value }&login_password=${ loginPassword.value }`);
});
```

### ajaxRequests.login()

```
login(formData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.xhr.open('POST', '//localhost/mouthblog/', true);
    this.xhr.send(formData);

    this.xhr.onload = () => {
      if (this.xhr.status == 200) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(this.xhr.statusText);
      }
    };

    this.xhr.onerror = () => {
      reject(this.xhr.statusText);
    };
  });
}
```

### this is the script that is supposed to run when form is sent

```
  if (isset($_POST['login_email']) && isset($_POST['login_password'])) {
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['login_email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
    $password = htmlentities($_POST['login_password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
    $login = new Login($email, $password);

    unset($login);
  }
```

### check for valid `$_SESSION` vars

```
  session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['id']) || !isset($_SESSION['name']) || !isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
  }
```

### login query (just incase it is needed)

```
class Login extends Connection {
  public function __construct($email, $password) {
    $this->connect();

    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `email`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=:email";
    $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute(
      [
        ':email' => htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15'),
      ]
    );

    // check if EMAIL exists
    if ($result) {
      $row             = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      $id              = htmlentities($row->id, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
      $name            = htmlentities($row->name, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
      $email           = htmlentities($row->email, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
      $hashed_password = htmlentities($row->password, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');

      // check if user input PASSWORD matches the unhashed PASSWORD in the database
      if (password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
        $_SESSION['id']    = htmlentities($id, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
        $_SESSION['name']  = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');
        $_SESSION['email'] = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15');

        header('Location: blog_roll.php');
      } else {
        header('Location: index.php');
      }
    } else {
      echo 'THAT EMAIL ADDRESS DOES NOT EXIST';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the content type for your ajax request

```
this.xhr.open('POST', '//localhost/mouthblog/', true);
this.xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
this.xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: Very, good catch. Little mistakes like that can cost hours of debugging time. So it doesn't redirect through the PHP script but refreshing the page does. Should I use window.location.href or window.location.replace() to do this? Does this matter?

Comment: Why use ajax if you're going to refresh the page anyway?

Comment: I'm saying that nothing visibly happens, so in order to be redirected, I have to refresh. I want to avoid refreshing which is where the `replace()` or `href` come in to play, just want advice on which to use in this situation.